# I am trying to do some simple hibernate program but i am getting error. Could you help some one?

Tags: hibernate

**Error:**

[image: Error]

**EmployeePOJO.hbm.xml :**

[image: Hibernate Mapping]

**hibernate.cfg.xml :**

[image: Configuration]

**ManageEmployee :**

[image: ManageEmployee]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please paste your code here, we do not accept image uploads of code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please edit your question to add [**sample data**](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. 
Provide them as [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and strictly [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). 
**DO NOT** post code or additional information in comments. 
Please ensure you have a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback. This is first experience for me, i will correct it in further post. I was fixed the problem myself and i got output. Even though i have doubt.

Comment: See manage Employee class. In that, .buildSessionFactory() method was strikes out but i unable to fix it. I don't know why it was strikes out but i am getting output. Could you tell me why was it happened...?

Answer (score -2):

If `EmployeePOJO.hbm.xml` file is in `hibernate.project.test` package, then in `hibernate.cfg.xml` you should provide the mapping as:

```
<mapping resource="hibernate/project/test/EmployeePOJO.hbm.xml" />
```

Comment: Yes, I have done the same in configuration file and i got output. Thank you for your valuable feedback...:)